# Github not loading svg images

Tags: github, svg

I am having an svg file with an embedded image. The image is hosted on imgur and is public. Whenever I am displaying the svg file on my local machine, it displays correctly, however, when I add the svg to the github repo, and see the svg, the github does not display the image correctly.

Is there something that I am doing wrong?

This is my svg file:

```
<svg version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <image href="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/naruto/images/2/27/Kakashi_Hatake.png/revision/latest?cb=20170628120149" x="50%" y="50px" height="200" width="200" transform="translate(-100,0)"/>
    
</svg>
```

[image]

[image: Github]

Comment: What do you mean by "Github not loading"? The main purpose of git is providing file storage for version control. Are you trying to view the svg file in the GitHub file viewer?

Comment: Yup, and when I am embedding the svg to the README, the image is not displayed

Comment: It seems possible that the image might be getting shrunk since the percentage doesn't define a minimum size for the image. Try setting `min-width="200" min-height="200"` on the `svg` tag and see if that makes it show up.

Comment: Its not even like that, I will attach a image showing how it is represented

Comment: I can verify that the SVG is at least valid since it can be added to a DOM and it shows the Naruto image. It is possible that GitHub is simply refusing to load the the external image link in the preview. Does it also show the broken image icon when added to your markdown document?

Comment: You can see the second image, it looks like this when I am adding the svg to the readme with img tag

Comment: This is another guess, but it might be getting blocked by the CORS strategy. Try adding `crossorigin="anonymous"` to the `image` tag.

Comment: Nope that didnt work, lets see the duplicate question